# Check if changes saved before unload

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload, onunload

I have the following JavaScript

**EDIT: included assignments for changesSaved**

```
 var changesSaved = true;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".applyChanges").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = (this).id;
            var dayofweek = document.getElementById("dayofweek" + id).value;
            var hour = document.getElementById("hour" + id).value;
            var duration = document.getElementById("duration" + id).value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ApplyChanges")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    dayofweek: dayofweek,
                    hour: hour,
                    duration: duration
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
                    $('#Calendar2').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
                    changesSaved = false;
                }
            });
        });
    });

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (changesSaved == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return ("You havent saved your changes. Are you sure you want to leave the page?")
    }
}
```

but the message is being prompted regardless of what `changesSaved` is set too.

What actually I actually get is the following:

[image]

or if `changesSaved` is set to false it says false instead.

Can I not do this ?

Comment: where are you setting `changesSaved`?

Comment: Add a `console.log(changesSaved)` and see what is the value inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body onbeforeunload="return bye()">

function bye(){
    if(changesSaved) {
        return "You havent saved your changes."
    }
}
```

This is how I do it.

or in pure JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (changesSaved) {
        return "You haven't saved your changes.";
    }
};
```

Comment: Interesting, I would just expect it to popup a dialog with `"undefined"` but seems to work in chrome

Comment: @Esailija - After you simplifying the code, it is less fancy now. (just kidding `;)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     var changesSaved = confirm("You havent saved your changes. Are you sure you want to leave the page?");
    if (changesSaved) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: When you click `cancel`, the page is still closing.

Comment: and you can do simply `return changesSaved;` or even `return confirm("...");`