# Delay page unload after submitting form

Tags: javascript, forms, delay

Is it possible to delay the moment when the unload method is called on a web page?
I have N pages and each page contains a form. I don't want users to click on a submit button so I simulated a click on the hidden submit button via javascript. This is activated everytime the user change page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    document.getElementById('submit_id').click(); 
}
```

This doesn't work but if I put an alert after .click ()

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    document.getElementById('submit_id').click(); 
    alert("submitting form"); 
}
```

everything works like a charm. This because the alert gives the form the time to actually submit its data; without the alert the page unloads before the form has been submitted and therefore the changes are not saved.

I tried to put a dummy setTimeout after .click()

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    document.getElementById('submit_id').click(); 
    setTimeout(console.log("dummy"), 200);
}
```

but it didn't work. Any help or feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873546/check-if-changes-saved-before-unload

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried onbeforeunload but I don't want to display a popup when the page changes. Ever. I just wnat the page to change, without any prompt to the user...

Comment: do you use jquery? if yes, try with unload, where you put ajax from save function: `$(window).unload( function () { do something } );`

Comment: Ehi Davor thanks again for your follow-up on this issue. I tried unload too but it's deprecated (http://api.jquery.com/unload/). Also it seems to work unconsistently among browsers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use jquery, you can try to save via ajax. and maybe adding async to false, not recomended but could work in your example if save function is really fast.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

here is how i save:

```
var $form = $('#formId');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
       // error
      },
    success: function (response) {
       // sucess
     }
});
```

Comment: I ended up using Jquery and solved it by sending a POST serialized message, thank you for your help.